# Evaluate the integral $\int_0^{3\pi/2} 3\lvert \sin x\rvert \; dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate the integral 
$$
\int_0^{3\pi/2} 3\lvert \sin x\rvert \; dx.
$$

My work: the integrand is actually:

| sinx | = sinx if sinx ≥ 0

| sinx | = - sinx if sinx < 0

hence:

∫ | sinx | dx = ∫ sinx dx = - cosx + C if sinx ≥ 0

∫ | sinx | dx = ∫ - sinx dx = cosx + C if sinx < 0

thus, joining these into a single statement:

∫ | sinx | dx = (- cosx) (| sinx | / sinx) + C

or, more precisely,

∫ | sinx | dx = (- cosx) sign(sinx) + C

sign(sinx) meaning 1 if sinx > 0 and - 1 if sinx < 0

is that correct ???

Answer (score 4):

This is more complicated than it has to be.

In the interval $[0,3\pi/2]$ it holds that $\sin x$ is nonnegative for $x\in[0,\pi]$ and negative for $x\in(\pi,3\pi/2]$. Thus, dividing the integral at $x=\pi$,
$$
\int_0^{3\pi/2}3|\sin x|\,dx=\int_0^\pi 3\sin x+\int_\pi^{3\pi/2}3(-\sin x)\,dx.
$$
Can you take it from here?

**Edit**
To simplify the calculations, one could also observe the symmetry of the sine function in the intervals $[0,\pi/2]$, $[\pi/2,\pi]$ and $[\pi,3\pi/2]$, and thus use that
$$
\int_0^{3\pi/2}3|\sin x|\,dx=3\int_0^{\pi/2}3\sin x\,dx.
$$

Comment: yes thank you ..

Answer (score 2):

The integral you are calculating is a **definite** integral and not an indefinite one. Therefore, it is better if you simply calculate it as

$$\int_0^\frac{3\pi}2 |\sin(x)|dx = \int_0^{\pi} |\sin(x)|dx + \int_\pi^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}|\sin(x)| dx$$

Comment: ↑ We have to stop doing things simultaneously. :)

Comment: @mickep Yeah, but hey, two answers are better than one.

Comment: Better than *n*one, even.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, you can tackle it geometrically.

We have
$$
\int_{x=0}^{3\pi/2} 3|\sin x| = 3\int_{x=0}^{\pi} \sin x + 3\int_{x=0}^{\pi/2} \sin x = -3\int_{x=0}^{\pi} D\cos x - 3\int_{x=0}^{\pi/2} D\cos x = 9
$$
by the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: 9 or -9 I got it -9

Comment: 9; $-3 cos (\pi) = 3$.

Comment: ok thanks , yes it's 9

Comment: Very nice @GudsonChou +1

Answer (score 0):

Notice, splitting the limit $$\int_{0}^{3\pi/2}3|\sin x|dx=3\int_{0}^{3\pi/2}|\sin x|dx$$  $$=3\left(\int_{0}^{\pi}|\sin x|dx+\int_{\pi}^{3\pi/2}|\sin x|dx\right)$$
$$=3\left(\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin x dx+\int_{\pi}^{3\pi/2}(-\sin x )dx\right)$$
$$=3\left([-\cos x]_{0}^{\pi}+[\cos x]_{\pi}^{3\pi/2}\right)$$
$$=3\left([1+1]+[0+1]\right)$$$$=3(3)=\color{red}{9}$$

Comment: The integral of a non-negative function becomes $-3$?

Comment: You are right. Thank you for observing the error.